# AsciiMath for "n choose r"

Tags: asciimath

What's the best notation for achieving this in AsciiMath:

[image: n choose r]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem that one can have a subscript without a base to which it attaches.  Using an empty element as a base this notation works: `{::}_nC_r`